# SQL merge to prevent double voting on a poll

Tags: sql, merge

I'm working on a polls application. The SQL schema is:

`polls -> * options (poll_id) -> * answers (option_id)`

Or: "a poll has many options and options can have answers (aka votes)"

I can only allow one vote **per user per poll**. This is the merge clause (that obviously does not work):

```
  merge into answers
  using (select count(*)
         from answers, options, polls
         where answers.option_id = options.id
         and options.poll_id = polls.id
         and polls.id = {poll_id}
         and answers.owner_id = {owner_id}) votes
  on (votes = 0)
  when matched then
  insert into answers values (NULL, {option_id}, {owner_id}, NOW())
```

Comment: `now()` is not a valid Oracle function.

Comment: Yeah, this query is from our dev server where we use H2. I need it to work with 11g, on dev I can stuf the method or anything if there is no standard SQL

Comment: what kind of indexes do you have on these primary keys?

Comment: perhaps you should use sub-queries with NOT IN's?

Answer (score 1):

If you never want to update, then a simple insert should do. I don't see the need for a merge at all:

```
insert into answers (some_value, option_id, owner_id, last_modified)
select null, {option_id}, {owner_id}, current_timestamp
from dual
where not exists (select 1 
                  from answers a
                    join options o on o.id = a.option_id
                    join polls p on p.id = o.poll_id
                  where a.owner_id = {owner_id}
                    and p.id = {polls_id}
```

I listed the columns for the insert clause explicitely because it's bad coding style to not do so. I only guessed your column names of course as you did not show us your table definitions.

Comment: @PabloFernandez: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25789/datadict.htm#CNCPT1219

Comment: This seems like almost standard sql, with the exception of `dual`. Isn't there a workaround for that? :)

Comment: @PabloFernandez: no, not really. Because Oracle and H2 are too different. But I think H2 supports the dual table if put into Oracle compatibility mode.

Comment: @PabloFernandez: I was wrong. H2 does not support these compatibility modes. I confused that with HSQLDB.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
MERGE INTO answers
USING 
(SELECT options.id 
             FROM options, polls
             WHERE options.poll_id = polls.id
             AND polls.id = {poll_id}
) options
ON (answers.option_id = options.id AND answers.owner_id = {owner_id})
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT INTO answers VALUES (NULL, {option_id}, {owner_id}, SYSDATE)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
    -- Do what you need to do for an update
```

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name OOPS.. Just replaced NOW with SYSDATE and forgot about `()`